# Select elements in Safari not respecting font set in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

I have a [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element in my DOM, and I'm applying my own font through some CSS:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: myFont;
        src: url('myFont.woff');
    }

    body select{
      font-family: myFont;  
    }
```

In Chrome, Firefox and IE the font looks fine. But in Safari v9.0.2, once the select is clicked, the font is lost.

I inspected it using [WhatFont](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html) and got the following:

[image]

So it looks like this *-apple-system - regular* font has overwritten my own.

**Is this standard Safari behavior?**

**Can I do anything about it?**

Comment: can you try `font-family: myFont !important` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this i hope it will be work.

<style>
@font-face {

font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';

src: url('/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),

url('/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

url('https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

url('/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#webfontfvFLBU0N') format('svg');

font-weight: normal;

font-style: normal;

}
</style>
```

Comment: What the heck is this?